How to maintain single band in raster export in QGIS
I'm working with a LiDAR DEM hosted on a server and I want to generate contour lines from it. I'm trying to 'Export -> Save As' to create a GeoTIFF, but the output that's created is a 4 band (RGBA) rather than the single band (1) like the source it's being generated from.
All the situations I could find were always going from multi to single or visa versa, but I haven't been able to find anything on forcing it to maintain the same number of bands.
How can I force QGIS to maintain the same number of bands as the source data when exporting to GeoTIFF?

What has generating contour lines got to do with it? Are you setting the raster layer symbology render type to "Contour" and then Export->Save As and selecting Rendered Image?

@user2856 My only option under Render Type is "Singleband color data". The source data is remote and is 4TB so not something I can pull down locally as a whole. So I thought my only option was to try to save the "viewport" data with the export, and then use Raster -> Extraction -> Contour. But like I said, all the exports end up being 4 band, so the second step doesn't work because it asks to select a single band.
